# Adding Auto-Implemented Property to class using Roslyn

Tags: c#, automatic-properties, roslyn

I'm trying to learn Roslyn by building an existing but simple application from the ground up, which seems to be a productive way to learn this.  Anyhow, I have the following code:

```
var root = (CompilationUnitSyntax)document.GetSyntaxRoot();

    // Add the namespace
    var namespaceAnnotation = new SyntaxAnnotation();
    root = root.WithMembers(
        Syntax.NamespaceDeclaration(
            Syntax.ParseName("ACO"))
                .NormalizeWhitespace()
                .WithAdditionalAnnotations(namespaceAnnotation));
    document = document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(root);

    // Add a class to the newly created namespace, and update the document
    var namespaceNode = (NamespaceDeclarationSyntax)root
        .GetAnnotatedNodesAndTokens(namespaceAnnotation)
        .Single()
        .AsNode();

    var classAnnotation = new SyntaxAnnotation();
    var baseTypeName = Syntax.ParseTypeName("System.Windows.Forms.Form");
    SyntaxTokenList syntaxTokenList = new SyntaxTokenList()
        {
            Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)
        };

    var newNamespaceNode = namespaceNode
        .WithMembers(
            Syntax.List<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(
                Syntax.ClassDeclaration("MainForm")
                    .WithAdditionalAnnotations(classAnnotation)
                    .AddBaseListTypes(baseTypeName)
                    .WithModifiers(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword))));

    root = root.ReplaceNode(namespaceNode, newNamespaceNode).NormalizeWhitespace();
    document = document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(root);


    var attributes = Syntax.List(Syntax.AttributeDeclaration(Syntax.SeparatedList(Syntax.Attribute(Syntax.ParseName("STAThread")))));


    // Find the class just created, add a method to it and update the document
    var classNode = (ClassDeclarationSyntax)root
        .GetAnnotatedNodesAndTokens(classAnnotation)
        .Single()
        .AsNode();

        var syntaxList = Syntax.List<MemberDeclarationSyntax>(
                Syntax.MethodDeclaration(
                    Syntax.ParseTypeName("void"), "Main")
                    .WithModifiers(Syntax.TokenList(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.PublicKeyword)))
                    .WithAttributes(attributes)
                    .WithBody(
                        Syntax.Block()));
        syntaxList.Add(Syntax.PropertyDeclaration(Syntax.ParseTypeName("System.Windows.Forms.Timer"), "Ticker"));
        var newClassNode = classNode
            .WithMembers(syntaxList);

    root = root.ReplaceNode(classNode, newClassNode).NormalizeWhitespace();
    document = document.UpdateSyntaxRoot(root);
```

Which outputs the following code in the IDocument.

```
namespace ACO
{
    public class MainForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        [STAThread]
        public void Main()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Although it should look more like this (notice I tried to add the Timer property)

```
namespace ACO
{
    public class MainForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
    public System.Windows.Forms.Timer Ticker {get; set;}

        [STAThread]
        public void Main()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Also, it appears that the code I'm writing for such a simple process seems excessive.  In addition to my main question can people offer suggestions on how I can go about this in a more elegant manner?  Maybe a link to a blog, or code snippets or something?

---

It turns out that I needed to change this line:

```
syntaxList.Add(Syntax.PropertyDeclaration(Syntax.ParseTypeName("System.Windows.Forms.Timer"), "Ticker"));
```

To this line:

```
syntaxList = syntaxList.Add(Syntax.PropertyDeclaration(Syntax.ParseTypeName("System.Windows.Forms.Timer"), "Ticker"));
```

However, now I get this output:

```
namespace ACO
{
    public class MainForm : System.Windows.Forms.Form
    {
        [STAThread]
        public void Main()
        {
        }

        System.Windows.Forms.Timer Ticker
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm not getting the "get; set;" text within the property.  Does anyone know what I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the reason why the property wasn't added is that `SyntaxList`s, like everything else in Roslyn, are immutable. Doesn't `Add()` return the updated `SyntaxList`? (I can't verify this right now, I haven't switched to the new CTP yet.)

And code like this in Roslyn can be very verbose, but you're making it more complicated than necessary. You don't have to update `root` after every change, if you build the syntax tree from bottom up: first create the members of the class, then the class, then the namespace. If you do that, you won't have to deal with all the annotations at all.

Comment: Your reminder of immutability lead me to realize what I was doing wrong which I posted below.  I will ask a separate question about how to actually build my particular Syntax Tree from the bottom up.

Comment: Here is the link to my new question on how do I go about building my Syntax Tree from the ground up as you suggested.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11351977/roslyn-ctp-building-a-syntaxtree-from-the-ground-up

Comment: In that other question of yours I've added a link to a tool called Quoter that can help in automatically generating Roslyn syntax API calls for any program:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2012/07/22/roslyn-code-quoter-tool-generating-syntax-tree-api-calls-for-any-c-program.aspx

Answer (score 7):

Using the new fluent API (.With...() methods) you can now use:

```
Syntax.PropertyDeclaration(Syntax.ParseTypeName("int"), "MyProperty")
      .WithAccessorList(
          Syntax.AccessorList(
              Syntax.List(
                  Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.GetAccessorDeclaration)
                        .WithSemicolonToken(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)),
                  Syntax.AccessorDeclaration(SyntaxKind.SetAccessorDeclaration)
                        .WithSemicolonToken(Syntax.Token(SyntaxKind.SemicolonToken)))));
```