# Api for working with a classes as OOP?

Tags: c#

I'm writing a 3rd party app that needs to read in .cs files and be able to manipulate classes, then ultimately save back to file.

The type of code I am looking at would be something like:

```
var classManager = new classManager(); 
var classes = classManager.LoadFromFile(filePath); 
var class = classes[0]; // Just illustrating more than 1 class can exist in a file

var prop = new ClassProperty {Type=MyType.GetType() };
prop.AddGet("return x+y < 50"); 

//stuff like prop.ReadOnly = true; 

class.AddProperty(prop); 

var method = new ClassMethod {signature="int id, string name"}; 
method.MethodBody = GetMethodBodyAsString(); //not writing out an entire method body here

class.AddMethod(method); 

class.SaveToFile(true); //Format code
```

Does such a library exist?

Comment: Why not just use reflection ? Of course this does not work on the sources, but I am just wondering if perhaps you didn't think about this option

Comment: @Philip, reflection cannot handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The .NET Compiler Platform Roslyn](https://roslyn.codeplex.com) is what you're looking for. It supports parsing and editting cs files. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11336712/adding-auto-implemented-property-to-class-using-roslyn) post for an example